# JPanel zoom out

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, zooming

The code below is perfect for zoom in and zoom out, but zoom out with restrictions. How to improve this code to allow zoom out without restrictions. In this example 
you can do zoom in ever you want, but zooming out is possible to return zoomed in panel to its original state.

```
public class FPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 400);    
private Rectangle2D[] rects = new Rectangle2D[50];

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(400, 400);
    jf.add(new JScrollPane(new FPanel()));
    jf.setVisible(true);
}    

public FPanel() {
    // generate rectangles with pseudo-random coords
    for (int i=0; i<rects.length; i++) {
        rects[i] = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                Math.random()*.8, Math.random()*.8, 
                Math.random()*.2, Math.random()*.2);
    }
    // mouse listener to detect scrollwheel events
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            updatePreferredSize(e.getWheelRotation(), e.getPoint());
        }
    });
}

private void updatePreferredSize(int n, Point p) {
    double d = (double) n * 1.08;
    d = (n > 0) ? 1/d : -d;

    int w = (int) (getWidth() * d);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * d);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);

    int offX = (int)(p.x * d) - p.x;
    int offY = (int)(p.y * d) - p.y;
    setLocation(getLocation().x-offX,getLocation().y-offY);

    getParent().doLayout();
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return preferredSize;
}

private Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Float();
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    for (Rectangle2D rect : rects) {
        r.setRect(rect.getX() * w, rect.getY() * h, 
                rect.getWidth() * w, rect.getHeight() * h);
        ((Graphics2D)g).draw(r);
    }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am correct, you want to zoom out the panel less than 100% (original size OR size of the JFrame).
Check this code.

```
public class FPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private static int prevN = 0;
private Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400,400);    
private Rectangle2D[] rects = new Rectangle2D[50];

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(400, 400);

    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();     // extra JPanel 
    containerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    FPanel zoomPanel = new FPanel();
    containerPanel.add(zoomPanel);

    jf.add(new JScrollPane(containerPanel));
    jf.setVisible(true);
}    

public FPanel() {
    // generate rectangles with pseudo-random coords
    for (int i=0; i<rects.length; i++) {
        rects[i] = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                Math.random()*.8, Math.random()*.8, 
                Math.random()*.2, Math.random()*.2);
    }
    // mouse listener to detect scrollwheel events
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            updatePreferredSize(e.getWheelRotation(), e.getPoint());
        }
    });
}

private void updatePreferredSize(int n, Point p) {

    if(n == 0)              // ideally getWheelRotation() should never return 0. 
        n = -1 * prevN;     // but sometimes it returns 0 during changing of zoom 
                            // direction. so if we get 0 just reverse the direction.

    double d = (double) n * 1.08;
    d = (n > 0) ? 1 / d : -d;

    int w = (int) (getWidth() * d);
    int h = (int) (getHeight() * d);
    preferredSize.setSize(w, h);

    int offX = (int)(p.x * d) - p.x;
    int offY = (int)(p.y * d) - p.y;
    getParent().setLocation(getParent().getLocation().x-offX,getParent().getLocation().y-offY); 
    //in the original code, zoomPanel is being shifted. here we are shifting containerPanel

    getParent().doLayout();             // do the layout for containerPanel
    getParent().getParent().doLayout(); // do the layout for jf (JFrame)

    prevN = n;
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return preferredSize;
}

private Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Float();
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    for (Rectangle2D rect : rects) {
        r.setRect(rect.getX() * w, rect.getY() * h, 
                rect.getWidth() * w, rect.getHeight() * h);
        ((Graphics2D)g).draw(r);
    }       
  }
}
```

Explaination : I have added an extra JPanel (`containerPanel`) which contains the `zoomPanel`. The `containerPanel` will accommodate for the empty space created when `zoomPanel` size is less than that of JFrame.
Also, the position sensitive zooming is only till the size of `zoomPanel` is greater than that of frame. Once the `zoomPanel` is smaller than JFrame, it will always be centered (by `GridBagLayout`).