# How to display the whole contents of a large JPanel in a small JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JPanel` with a size of 816 x 1056 pixels (size of a standard typewriting paper). Is there any way of displaying the whole `JPanel` and its content without altering its actual size, in a small `JFrame`? Is there a way of like zooming it out?

Comment: Will this JPanel hold components such as JButtons, JLabels, JTextComponents and such that must shrink as well? And if so, must they still be usable by the user?

Comment: No sir. it only contains a `JLabel` which is its background image. Imagine this Panel as a print preview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPanel zoom out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760849/jpanel-zoom-out)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy method to zoom a `JPanel` out, but you can do it via double-buffering:

```
private void paintPanel (Graphics2D g)
{
    // here goes the code of your paint() or paintComponent() method
}

/** Draw content into an Image, shrink it, and display it. */
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    // paint image
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    paintPanel(img.createGraphics());

    // shrink image and paint it
    g.drawImage(img, 0,0, WIDTH,HEIGHT, 0,0, MAX_WIDTH,MAX_HEIGHT, null);
}
```

This will paint everything on a `BufferedImage` with the size `MAX_WIDTH` x `MAX_HEIGHT`. Then, the Image will be shrinked into the size `WIDTH` x `HEIGHT` and then displayed.

Comment: I'd like to up-vote this, but the key part, the part marked `/* do something */` is missing.

Comment: This is the part where the old paint method goes into, this was not posted in the question

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting his question, but when I think of JPanel, I think of the panel and all its components which would not be easy or straightforward to shrink.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question too, but I think he has just a Component (`JPanel`) where he paints things into, and he don't care about the subcomponents - I think if he had, he would have already posted a comment to say this

Comment: Sirs. It only contains a `JLabel` which is the panel's background image. Imagine the panel as a print preview. Just to clarify I'm a she.

Comment: @PaulineFrancisco If it only contains a `JLabel` with the background Image, remove the `JLabel` from your panel and write `g.drawImage(yourImage, 0, 0, null)` into the `paintPanel` method

Comment: will it zoom out the panel via mouse scroll?

Comment: @PaulineFrancisco It will zoom out the panel to the size `WIDTH` x `HEIGHT`. The code is only a template, feel free to append a `MouseListener` for your project

Comment: Sir I think I just found the answer. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760849/jpanel-zoom-out/17584506#17584506]

Comment: without reseting custom painting by using super.paintComponent is this answer quite wrong

Comment: @mKorbel The behavior you described will be handled in the `update` method, and the OP mentioned that he will paint an image into the panel, but if you want to explicitly set the background color you need to call `super.paintComponent()`, of course